# Image of a product of opens

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

This is a general topology question.

Let $k < n$ be positive integers. Suppose we have *opens* $U \subset \mathbf R^k$ and $V \subset \mathbf R^{n-k}$ and a continuous and injective map
$$f: U \times V \hookrightarrow \mathbf R^{n}.$$

I cannot think of an example of such $U,V,f$ such that the image of $f$ is not an open (in $\mathbf R^{n}$) but I see no reason why it should be open. I am very inclined to think that there are examples were $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is not open.

Could you please provide such an example?

[I first thought that  a fattened version of the usual "non-submanifold" "looking like a $\sigma$" would do the job, but it does not seem to.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such examples, though it is not trivial to prove. It is a classical result by Brouwer: [Invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)